# conda create environment with new version numpy

Tags: conda

I'm new in python and conda. I'm using the default version of python (2.7.14) on mac, and I want to use pandas 0.22 that I already installed (with conda); for that, I installed numpy 1.14 with conda as well, but when I tried to run a script importing pandas (import pandas) it just say:

```
ImportError: this version of pandas is incompatible with numpy < 1.9.0
your numpy version is 1.8.0rc1.
Please upgrade numpy to >= 1.9.0 to use this pandas version
```

I think that python is calling the default numpy version that comes with python 2.7 (in:         /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/).

My question is, if I create a environment for this module with conda, I mean something like this:

```
conda create --name numpy1.14 anaconda=4.4.7 numpy=1.14.0 python=2.7

export PATH=~/anaconda/envs/numpy1.14/bin:$PATH
```

python 2.7 will call numpy 1.14.0 when it is running from any given script, or when I import pandas ??? it will import the new version (1.14.0) or the old ??? it is any way to import and specific version of any module in a script running the default version of python in mac ????

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the environment variable PYTHONPATH set?

Comment: no, no yet, how can I Add, I was looking for an appropriated way, but I'm not sure, is in this way ??: export PYTHONPATH=/Users/my_count/miniconda2/lib      I just want it for the default version of python (2.7) thanks !!

Comment: No, you should not set PYTHONPATH. In addition, you should not set the PATH to use an environment, you should use the conda activate scripts, most likely `source activate numpy1.14`